# Using one map, multiple layouts, each with different layers in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: layers, maps, layouts, arcgis-pro

I was wondering whether it's possible in ArcGIS Pro to create multiple layouts for one map, which contains different layers (e.g. aerial photo, buildings and soiltype).

After prepping the map in 'map view', I'd add a new layout for e.g. a map of the building, and add the map frame. In the contents view I'm toggling layers on and off for what I need in that particular layout (e.g. aerial photo + buildings). Then, I'd add another new layout for the soil type, toggling layers on and off in contents (e.g. aerial photo + soiltype). Unfortunately, it seems that toggling layers on and off in contents view affects all layouts.

Is there any way to toggle layers on and off within a single layout view of the same map, without affecting the other layouts?

I just can't seem to figure this out but there must be something I'm not grasping about ArcGIS Pro, because this seems like pretty basic functionality.

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reproduce what you are describing I did the following using ArcGIS Pro 1.4:

1. Create a Blank Project called C:\Temp\TestProject
2. Insert a New Basemap
3. Create Fishnet of 4 squares (TestFC; polylines) and 4 labels (TestFC_label)
4. Zoom Layer on TestFC
5. Insert A4 Layout
6. On Layout insert two Map Frames using the Basemap from above
7. Turning a layer on/off in either of the Map Frames or in the Basemap affects that layer's visibility in both Map Frames and the Basemap

[image]

I think what you are describing is by design in ArcGIS Pro.

I think what you may be looking for (perhaps submit an ArcGIS Idea) is a new type of Map Frame where the layers are dependent on what is in the Map/Basemap but the visibility settings can be independent.

However for now I think you may need to copy your Map/Basemap and have the separate Map Frames access different Maps/Basemaps.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is to use QGIS. In QGIS one can create multiple "themes” which are in essence views of the map with different layers displaying. Layouts can then be tied to specific themes. You can also create multiple symbologies for a single layer and those symbologies can be used in defining themes, thus minimizing the number of layers needed in a map. If you need different queries for different symbologies, QGIS supports “rules-based” symbologies, which are, essentially, queries applied to symbologies.

There’s more to this story, but this describes the gist of it.

Answer (score 1):

I could not figure this out either. I duplicated the map and then created two layouts, one pointing to each map. In each layout I then toggled on/off the layers I wanted to display. The simplest way I found to duplicate the map: in the contents pane, right click "Map" then select "Save as map file". Then on the Insert tab select "Insert map" and select your saved map file. This should create two identical maps that you can then create two layouts with different map frames. I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use another map frame for each layout.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Catalog pane, right click on Maps. Select New map option (e.g., it is called Map1). Copy your desired layer on Map1. On your layout insert two Map Frame. For the first Map frame select Map and for the second Map frame select Map1.